# Django form - use different pre defined date ranges for different choices

Tags: javascript, html, django, forms, django-forms

I have a Django form where the user can select a variable in a choice field, start date and end date in a select date widget. For different variables, the possible start and end dates varies. The form works, but only with one pre-defined date range for all variables. How can I change the possible start and end dates according to the variable?

```
from django import forms
from datetime import datetime 

Parameter_CHOICES = [
    ('', 'Wähle ein Umweltvariable'),
    ('niederschlag', 'Niederschlag [L/m²]'),
    ('bodentemperatur_5cm', 'Bodentemperatur in 5cm Tiefe [°C]')
]

class DataForm(forms.Form):
    parameter = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select,
        choices=Parameter_CHOICES)
    start_date = forms.DateField(label='Beginn:', widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=list(range(2007,2023))))
    end_date = forms.DateField(label='Ende:', initial=datetime.now, widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=list(range(2007,2023))))
```

What i need is to set the
`years=list(range(2007,2023))`
for niederschlag
and for bodentemperatur_5cm to
`years=list(range(1991,2023))`

Is it possible to do this in the forms.py or do I have to make this in javascript/html?

**Update**
I try to solve it with jQuery, but I stuck.
I try to change the Years Range choicec according to parameter with this function:

```
$("#id_parameter").on('change', function(){
        var parameter = $("#id_parameter").val();
        if (parameter == 'niederschlag') {
            $("#id_start_date_year").val(2007);
        }
        if (parameter == 'bodentemperatur_5cm') {
            $("#id_start_date_year").val(1991);
        }
```

But this only change the value the user can see first. How can I change the possible years or range after the user select the parameter with jQuery?

Comment: To set the ranges within django you would have to separate the parameter choice from the rest of the data. This could be solved with a small choice picking page (with a form or simply different buttons). If you want the ranges to be really changed in the frontend dynamically you have to use javascript. Technically both is possible, the choice is your what you really want to achive.

Comment: @dgw With different button, you mean I hide all other buttons according to user choice? But then I also have to use JavaScript right? But good idea, I think I will go this way, thanks!

Comment: With buttons I meant ... create a simple intermediate django page that lists your two choices as buttons (button 1 -> "Niederschlag", button 2 -> "Bodentemperatur") and then use the information within the new view to configure the year ranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### There are 2 solutions to this that I can think of:

#### With views

First create the forms, the first that lets you choose the type, the second initiates the form for the options you make in "get_first_and_second_year":

```
# forms

class DataForm(forms.Form): 
    Parameter_CHOICES = [
        ('', 'Wähle ein Umweltvariable'),
        ('niederschlag', 'Niederschlag [L/m²]'),
        ('bodentemperatur_5cm', 'Bodentemperatur in 5cm Tiefe [°C]')
    ]   
    parameter = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget = forms.Select,
        choices = Parameter_CHOICES
    )

class DatePickForm(forms.Form):
    start_date = forms.DateField(label='Beginn:', widget=forms.SelectDateWidget())
    end_date = forms.DateField(label='Ende:', initial=datetime.now, widget=forms.SelectDateWidget())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # get kwargs
        first_year = kwargs.pop('first_year', None)
        second_year = kwargs.pop('second_year', None)
        # super
        super(DatePickForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # initialize form fields
        self.fields['start_date'] = forms.DateField(
            label='Beginn:', 
            widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(
                years=list(range(first_year,second_year))
            )
        )
        self.fields['end_date'] = forms.DateField(
            label='Ende:', 
            widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(
                years=list(range(first_year,second_year))
            )
        )
```

Make the call for the page using different views:

```
# call in views


@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def date_form_view(request):
    form = DataForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #................................................................
        #    treat form
        #................................................................
        redirect('date_pick', form_choice=form_choice)
    # render with context 
    context = {'form': form}
    render(request, "", context)


def get_first_and_second_year(form_choice):
    # return first and second year depending on form choice
    match form_choice:
        case 'niederschlag':
            return first_year, second_year 
        case 'bodentemperatur_5cm':
            return first_year, second_year
        case _:
            return 0, 0


@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def date_form_view(request, form_choice):
    # dont forget to map url to this view with the argument
    
    first_year, second_year = get_first_and_second_year(form_choice)
    form = DatePickForm(request.POST or None, first_year=first_year, second_year=second_year)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #................................................................
        #    treat form
        #................................................................        
        start_date = request.POST.get('start_date')
        # ...

    context = {'form': form}
    render(request, "", context)
```

#### With ajax (smoother interface, harder to code):

**Ajax post/get calls explanation** https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/work-with-ajax-django

Pass a json string to to the view that describes the different actions for each form_choice:

And prepend the html with the form for the form_choice.